# How to store useful information about a polygon drawn by google maps drawing tool and then again draw it by that information?

Tags: database, google-maps, google-maps-drawing

I am trying to draw a polygon with maps drawing tool. Now I want to store useful information about that polygon in the database so I can again draw that same polygon by retrieving the data.
what is that information and how I can use that to draw same polygon?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a Data type of Varchar/ Specific data type (depending of Database in use) in the table and store the metadata of Polygon or any shape as XML/JSON.

Here's link [a https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingResults](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingResults)

Comment: Actually, I want to know that metadata. I didn't get any metadata for this.Please Help